# Why Windsor's Typed Factory passes to constructor argument it received first time?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Test below fails on last `Assert()` with this message:
  Expected: "arg2"
  But was:  "arg1"

It seems when `"arg1"` passed first time - typed factory remembers this and ignores `"arg2"` from second call. Why?

```
public class E
{
    public string Arg { get; set; }

    public E(string arg)
    {
        Arg = arg;
    }
}

public interface IEFactory
{
    E Create(string arg);
}

[Test]
public void TypedFactoryWorksAsExpected()
{
    var windsor = new WindsorContainer();
    windsor.Kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
    windsor.Register(
        Component.For<E>(), 
        Component.For<IEFactory>().AsFactory());

    var factory = windsor.Resolve<IEFactory>();
    var e1 = factory.Create("arg1");
    var e2 = factory.Create("arg2");

    Assert.AreEqual("arg1", e1.Arg);

    // This line fails with  message: 
    // 'Expected: "arg2" But was: "arg1".'
    Assert.AreEqual("arg2", e2.Arg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windsor components are singletons by default. Your `E` is a singleton because you didn't specify anything else. The second call does not ignore the argument but reuses the previous instance because it is a singleton.

You have to define that `E` is a transient:

```
windsor.Register(Component.For<E>().LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Comment: Yeah, I already figured that out and was writing my own answer, but you've outrun me. That's correct answer indeed.